# How to generate the invoice with laravel + cashier when using product checkouts

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

For subscriptions, the invoices are easy to generate. Also for 'normal' single charges.

Is there a way to generate a invoice, when using a single charge through a hosted stripe checkout. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#product-checkouts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, [Laravel supports single charges with Invoices](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#charge-with-invoice).

Comment: that is not using the stripe checkout page. i had contact with a stripe developer, and he told me checkout in payment mode does not support generating invoices.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood your question, but glad to hear you found the correct answer!